# otest crash with -[id<NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender> userCredential:]

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4, xcodebuild, afnetworking

We have a class that uses `AFHTTPClient` and `AFHTTPRequestOperation`'s internally. In development, we connect to a server with an invalid SSL Certificate, so we have this code in the method that returns the request operations:

```
if (self.allowInvalidSSLCertificates)
    {
        [operation setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {
            if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
                [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            }
        }];

        [operation setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:^BOOL(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace) {
            return YES;
        }];
    }
```

which effectively is the same as defining `_AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_`, but we needed to do this at run-time.
This works perfectly on Xcode, ignores the invalid certificate, and all our functional tests pass. The problem comes when we run them from the command line using `xcodebuild`.  As soon as it's going to run the first test, it crashes:

`Run test case <testMethodName>
Test Case '-[<TestCaseClass> <testMethodName>]' started.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include: line 415: 47744 Bus error: 10           "${THIN_TEST_RIG}" "${OTHER_TEST_FLAGS}" "${TEST_BUNDLE_PATH}"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:451: error: Test rig '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/otest' exited abnormally with code 138 (it may have crashed).`

If we get rid of that code, and don't ignore the SSL certificate being invalid, tests don't pass, because the connection fails, but nothing crashes.

This is the crash log in Console:

```
Process:         otest [35957]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/otest
Identifier:      otest
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [35952]

Date/Time:       2012-05-29 15:46:37.398 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.4 (11E53)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  7  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/otest
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-0000000000003000 [    8K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/otest

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x98908c22 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x989081f6 mach_msg + 70
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0045e10a __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 186
3   CoreFoundation                  0x003c1550 __CFRunLoopRun + 1312
4   CoreFoundation                  0x003c0d84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
5   CoreFoundation                  0x003c0c9b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   Foundation                      0x0004e40f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
7   Foundation                      0x000899e8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 73
8   Functional Tests                0x052f37d5 -[<TestCaseClass> <TestMethodName>] + 1253 (<TestCaseClass>.m:564)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x003f04ed __invoking___ + 29
10  CoreFoundation                  0x003f0407 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 167
11  SenTestingKit                   0x201039c4 -[SenTestCase invokeTest] + 184
12  SenTestingKit                   0x20103868 -[SenTestCase performTest:] + 183
13  SenTestingKit                   0x201034a9 -[SenTest run] + 82
14  SenTestingKit                   0x20106db2 -[SenTestSuite performTest:] + 106
15  SenTestingKit                   0x201034a9 -[SenTest run] + 82
16  SenTestingKit                   0x20106db2 -[SenTestSuite performTest:] + 106
17  SenTestingKit                   0x201034a9 -[SenTest run] + 82
18  SenTestingKit                   0x20105e97 +[SenTestProbe runTests:] + 174
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0048bd51 +[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 65
20  otest                           0x0000231c 0x1000 + 4892
21  otest                           0x000025be 0x1000 + 5566
22  otest                           0x00002203 0x1000 + 4611
23  otest                           0x00001f8d 0x1000 + 3981
24  otest                           0x00001f31 0x1000 + 3889

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9890b90a kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x01029372 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 918
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x01027be1 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 53

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9890b02e __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabcccf _pthread_wqthread + 773
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabe6fe start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9890b02e __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabcccf _pthread_wqthread + 773
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabe6fe start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9890b02e __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabcccf _pthread_wqthread + 773
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabe6fe start_wqthread + 30

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9890b02e __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabcccf _pthread_wqthread + 773
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabe6fe start_wqthread + 30

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x98908c22 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x989081f6 mach_msg + 70
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0045e10a __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 186
3   CoreFoundation                  0x003c15d5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1445
4   CoreFoundation                  0x003c0d84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
5   CoreFoundation                  0x003c0c9b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   Foundation                      0x0004e40f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
7   Foundation                      0x0004e2d3 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   Functional Tests                0x054fb7f5 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] + 133 (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:146)
9   Foundation                      0x0001a4d6 -[NSThread main] + 76
10  Foundation                      0x0001a447 __NSThread__main__ + 1258
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabaed9 _pthread_start + 335
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabe6de thread_start + 34

Thread 7 Crashed:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   CoreFoundation                  0x0039a811 CFArrayGetCount + 17
1   Security                        0x00dae356 SecTrustCopyExceptions + 35
2   CFNetwork                       0x00b31764 SocketStream::securityAcceptPeerTrust_NoLock(unsigned char) + 150
3   CFNetwork                       0x00b39fd4 SocketStream::setProperty(void const*, __CFString const*, void const*) + 2754
4   CFNetwork                       0x00b39508 virtual thunk to SocketStream::setProperty(void const*, __CFString const*, void const*) + 43
5   CFNetwork                       0x00b3abad ReadStreamCallbacks::_setProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*, void*) + 53
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00429b10 CFReadStreamSetProperty + 160
7   CFNetwork                       0x00b3ab60 HTTPReadFilter::streamSetProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*) + 266
8   CFNetwork                       0x00bd4345 non-virtual thunk to HTTPReadFilter::streamSetProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*) + 41
9   CFNetwork                       0x00b37308 CFNetworkReadStream::httpStreamSetProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*, void*) + 38
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00429b10 CFReadStreamSetProperty + 160
11  CFNetwork                       0x00b419f4 HTTPNetStreamInfo::streamSetProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*) + 404
12  CFNetwork                       0x00b41858 non-virtual thunk to HTTPNetStreamInfo::streamSetProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*) + 41
13  CFNetwork                       0x00b37308 CFNetworkReadStream::httpStreamSetProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*, void*) + 38
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00429b10 CFReadStreamSetProperty + 160
15  CFNetwork                       0x00be3e29 HTTPProtocol::useCredential(_CFURLCredential const*, _CFURLAuthChallenge*) + 125
16  CFNetwork                       0x00bfa98f URLConnectionLoader::loaderUseCredential(_CFURLCredential const*) + 117
17  CFNetwork                       0x00bfa47a URLConnectionLoader::LoaderConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XLoaderEvent, XLoaderEventParams>*, long) + 140
18  CFNetwork                       0x00b2273b URLConnectionLoader::processEvents() + 107
19  CFNetwork                       0x00bf7117 non-virtual thunk to URLConnectionInstanceData::multiplexerClientPerform() + 21
20  CFNetwork                       0x00b20fbf MultiplexerSource::perform() + 259
21  CoreFoundation                  0x0045e94f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
22  CoreFoundation                  0x003c1b43 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
23  CoreFoundation                  0x003c1424 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
24  CoreFoundation                  0x003c0d84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
25  CoreFoundation                  0x003c0c9b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
26  Foundation                      0x00108e30 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 398
27  Foundation                      0x0001a4d6 -[NSThread main] + 76
28  Foundation                      0x0001a447 __NSThread__main__ + 1258
29  libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabaed9 _pthread_start + 335
30  libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabe6de thread_start + 34

Thread 8:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9890ab42 __select + 10
1   CoreFoundation                  0x003f27cb __CFSocketManager + 939
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabaed9 _pthread_start + 335
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9aabe6de thread_start + 34

Thread 7 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x00000002  ecx: 0x0d651da4  edx: 0x05012980
  edi: 0x0039a80d  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0xb038bbb8  esp: 0xb038bba0
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010286  eip: 0x0039a811   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x00000000
Logical CPU: 4

Binary Images:
.....
```

Googling for that crash doesn't show anything similar. It crashes inside `CFNetwork` with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, and I can't see any memory management issue in AFNetworking or in my code that could be causing this. Also this doesn't happen the 100% of the times (I'd say around the 80%), so I can't help to think there's some kind of race condition. Perhaps we're doing something with a non thread-safe object in the wrong thread? Again, haven't seen anything in particular in this regard.

Using Xcode 4.3.2 on Mac OSX 10.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said on github, I also got this crash (same stackstrace), but it doesn't crash when an iOS Simulator is started...

Edit : found a solution (not very convenient, but continuous integration came back :-)

```
@interface NSURLRequest()

+ (void)setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:(BOOL)b forHost:(NSString *)host;

@end

@implementation SomeTests

- (void)setUp
{
    [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:@"domain.com"];
}
...
```

Comment: Can you share that solution? :)

Comment: This solution is OK for UnitTests, but not for production use as it break SSL security down and is a private API.

Comment: Submitted an edit to your answer that explains a little bit more. Thanks for the answer, it does work for tests ;)